# gmap3 markers into a cluster at the same position

Tags: jquery-gmap3

On gmap3 when you have multiple markers with the exact same location, no matter how deep you zoom in, you won’t get a chance to see markers. If you remove clustering on a certain zoom levels (or remove it at all), you’ll see only one marker there(the top one), others will remain hidden underneath, since they stack on top of each other.My main problem is how to show the markers of the cluster with the exact same location

Answer (score 0):

That a bit late for an answer but maybe someone got the same problem recently...

The solution for this particluar issue may be solved by diverse approaches:

1) use the spiderfier https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

2) add an listener to the cluster and write your own paginator. This is my favorite solution right now, especially when more than 30 items are placed on the the same location.